# How to fix error line number offset in Sublime Text when compiling for Arduino

Tags: debugging, gcc

When compiling for Arduino via the Stino plugin line numbers are not represented correctly in the output. For example, I have an error on line 117 however the output is: `sketch_name.ino.cpp:136:1: error:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`#line` preprocessor directive](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html) is used to tell GCC both what the next line should be numbered as and what filename should be reported, and the plugin is not generating them properly. This is therefore a Stino bug.

Comment: In that case, couldn't you just add a `#line 1` at the top of the ino file?

Comment: Sure, but that shouldn't be the responsibility of the programmer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried the #line 1 suggestion @Gerben however the errors are still showing on the wrong line.

Comment: Also thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've added this to the issues on the Stino github repository.